# Get a job step to depend on an input variable

Tags: github-actions

I'm trying to use an `inputs` in an `if:` statement and it is failing.

I have a step:

```
       -name: Test 1
        env:
          PRERELEASE_VERSION: ${{ inputs.prerelease_version }}
          PRERELEASE_VERSIONX: ${{ inputs.prerelease_version == 'release' }}
        run: |
          echo hello $PRERELEASE_VERSION goodbye
          echo hello $PRERELEASE_VERSIONX goodbye
```

and when I start this code with the variable set to `release`, I see:

```
hello release goodbye
hello true goodbye
```

But if I try:

```
      - name: Test 2
        if: inputs.prelease_version == 'release'
        run:
          echo hello $PRERELEASE_VERSION goodbye
```

the step is skipped.  I've also tried putting the expression inside `${{ ... }}` and it is still skipped.

Just as an experiment, I also tried:

```
      - name: Test 3
        if: ${{ inputs.prelease_version }} == 'release'
        run:
          echo hello $PRERELEASE_VERSION goodbye
```

The results were even worse.  The code always ran, no matter what the value of the input variable.
The variable `prelease_version` is declared as an input on my workflow_dispatch with type `string`.

Is there anyway to create an `if:` statement using an input value?

Answer (score 0):

You should surround all  the statement with `${{ ... }`, as example:

```
  - name: Test 3
    if: ${{ inputs.prelease_version  == 'release' }}
    run:
      echo hello $PRERELEASE_VERSION goodbye
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work.  See my comment after the code for "Test 2"

Comment: very strange....